# How to run unittest with distutils in python3.3

Tags: python, python-3.3, distutils

Is there a way to run unittests for a module with setup.py using distutils? python3.3 distutils doesn't seem to support the 'test_suite' option:

In setup.py I have the following code:
      test_suite = 'test.run_tests',

Answer (score 0):

No distutils version supports test integration: it’s a setuptools add-on.

unittest in 2.7 and 3.2 gained support for auto-discovering tests, so even if you can’t run `python setup.py test` there’s still `python -m unittest`.